# strcpy function: C

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I am trying to implement

```
void strcpyy(char *s, char *t){
    while(*s++ = *t++){
    }
}
```

which is an example from K&R. The implementation should be fairly easy but for some reason, that is not the case for me at the moment. So I have the following

```
int main(){
    char *mess = "hello world";
    char *mess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
    char *aess;

    strcpyy(aess, mess);

    printf("%s", aess);

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run the program, I keep on getting a big list of errors each time I run with `-Wall`. I would think that to implement and use `strcpyy`, you would have to malloc space to copy the string and once you do so, you should be able to print out `aess` which theoratically should contain a copy of `mess`. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I see you are a new user. Did you know that you should choose one answer as accepted? For this you use the green bird icon next to the number between triangles to the left of the answer. You can also use the up triangle (upvote) on any answer to indicate that it was useful, or the down triangle (downvote) to indicate that it is counterproductive.

Comment: isn't give you error like `error: redefinition` for your `char *mess` variable? Also where you allocated space for `char *aess;`?. First make code error free then think about result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good practice to pay attention to the error messages, especially to the first message (others often are the consequences of the first error). The error message surely indicated the line number corresponding to the line with malloc, and most probably told you what's the problem there.

Correct your program to read:

```
char *mess = "hello world";
char *aess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
```

or the complete function is:

```
int main(){
    char *mess = "hello world";
    char *aess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);

    strcpyy(aess, mess);

    printf("%s", aess);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that your line

```
char *mess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
```

overwrites the first line

```
char *mess = "hello world";
```

and the line

```
char *aess;
```

leaves the variable unassigned.

The compile error is because the compiler cannot choose between

```
char *mess = "hello world";
```

and

```
char *mess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
```

which introduce a new variable each but with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The program will look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void strcpyy( char *s, const char *t )
{
    while ( *s++ = *t++ );
}

int main( void )
{
    char *t = "hello world";
    char *s = ( char * )malloc( strlen( t ) + 1 );

    strcpyy( s, t );

    printf( "%s\n", s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Matt McNabb I am sorry but I do not follow bad advices.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, why do you think that is bad advice?

Comment: @RSahu  It is simply a stupid advice. It had a sense when  compilers were very old but now there is no any sense. First of all can you say what type you allocate in this statement p = malloc( n * sizeof( p ) ); ? Secondly it is not excluded that the code will be used with a C++ compiler then your life will not be enough to insert everywhere the casting because C++ compiler does allow such constructions. It is a good style explicitly to specify the casting that to make the program more readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is not excluded that this code will be used with a Perl interpreter, please fix

Comment: @VladfromMoscow to make your code more readable, please replace with  `(int)((int (*)(char const *,...))(printf))((char const *)"%s\n", (char *)s );`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
char *mess = "hello world";
char *mess = (char *) malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
char *aess;
```

to

```
char *mess = "hello world";
char *aess = malloc(strlen(mess) + 1);
```

`mess` is a string literal, which is hold in read-only memory. you were overwriting it and losing string that you wanted to copy. you need to assign some space for place where you want to copy characters, in your case `aess` variable. also, remember to `free(aess);` at the end of your program. if not, you'll get memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

why are you declaring and defining `mess` two times? never declare two variables with the same name if they have the same scope ,by doing this you confuse the compiler;
I'd recommed using `strdup` like this :

```
int main(){
char *mess = strdup("hello world");
char *aess;

strcpyy(aess, mess);

printf("%s", aess);

return 0;
```

}

or just a plain array like this

```
int main(){

char mess[] = "hello world";
char *aess;

strcpyy(aess, mess);

printf("%s", aess);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This doesn't fix the more serious problem. Your destination (`aess`) is an uninitialized pointer.